# C# linq-SQL and SQL null join return different result

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, join

I'm using left (null) join to check which data does table A have and table B does not.

SQL is:

```
select a.* from a
left join b 
on a.sid=b.sid
and a.pid=b.pid
where b.sid = null
and a.pid='r'
```

this returns 0 row, that is as expected.

but, C# linq-SQL :

```
from a in entities.a
join b in entities.b
on new { sid = (int)a.sid, pid = a.pid}
equals new { sid = (int)b.sid, pid = b.pid}
into j
from x in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
where x.sid== null
&& a.pid=="r"
select a
```

this return thousands of rows.

so anyone tell me why..?

thanks!

Comment: your sql query makes no sense: you join on `a.sid = b.sid` and further on your where clause says `b.sid = null`

Answer (score 0):

They are very different.  This sql is closer:

```
select a.* from a
left join b 
on isnull(cast(a.sid as varchar(max)),'')+'#'+isnull(cast(a.pid as varchar(max)),'')==
   isnull(cast(b.sid as varchar(max)),'')+'#'+isnull(cast(a.pid as varchar(max)),'')
where b.sid == null
and a.pid=='r'
```

Comment: You want a null list?  sure just do this `var result = new List<typeof entities.a>();`

Comment: @BennyAe - to be more direct, your SQL is **not good** -- it will **never** return any results.  Maybe you are not telling us the whole story?

Answer (score 0):

@Hogan is right. Your LINQ statement is very different from the SQL one.

The combination `join` + `into` is called a [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), and has no SQL equivalent. It puts in each `j` a collection of `b`. It does not filter the results in `a`, and therefore, you get as many `j`'s as there are in `entitities.a`. However, the `equals` clause is always false because C# creates two different anonymous types at compile time. So, each `j` becomes an empty `Enumerable`, and `DefaultIfEmtpy` returns a collection with a single empty instance of `b` (all properties null), so the condition `b.sid == null` is true for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the SQL is running with  [ANSI_NULLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) ON , which may return zero records.
and the linq is running by default on  ANSI_NULLS OFF.

To Check this execute sql query in sql server with both

```
Set ANSI_NULLS ON
select a.* from a
left join b 
on a.sid=b.sid
and a.pid=b.pid
where b.sid = null
and a.pid='r'
```

and then with

```
Set ANSI_NULLS OFF
select a.* from a
left join b 
on a.sid=b.sid
and a.pid=b.pid
where b.sid = null
and a.pid='r'
```

you may get different results

Also the linq you are using is almost right except you don't need to type cast with (int)

```
from a in entities.a
join b in entities.b
on new { sid = a.sid, pid = a.pid}
equals new { sid = b.sid, pid = b.pid} into j
from x in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
where x.sid== null
&& a.pid=="r"
select a
```

OR alternatively

```
from a in entities.a
    join b in entities.b
    on a.sid equals b.sid into j
    from x in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where a.pid  == b.pid &&  x.sid== null
    && a.pid=="r"
    select a
```